# Genymotion Virtual Device Blocks Physical Device

Tags: android, genymotion, android-studio-2.0

I am learning Android development using Android Studio. I have PC with AMD CPU so x86 Virtual Device doesn't work. So I installed Genymotion. It works well, apps testing is very fast. But I have a strange problem.
I have a physical android phone which I also use to test apps.
I don't have a tablet, so I created a virtual tablet in Genymotion.
When I start the virtual tablet, the physical device disappears from ADB list. 
I monitored Android Device Monitor. When virtual device starts, the physical device stops. Its console says "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".
If I want to reuse the physical device, I have to turn off the virtual device, turn USB debugging OFF in physical device, then disconnect USB cable from physical device, the again reconnect it, and finally turn ON USB debugging again.
I want to run both devices simultaneously so I can test my apps on both devices (of course one at a time). Each time, disconnect and reconnect process is very tedious.
Anyone have any solution? Or am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What device do you need? https://www.ironlab.io/ allows debugging on real devices. They are in free beta now.